# NSButton with CALayer flips the image when clicked

Tags: objective-c, calayer

I've got an `NSButton` with an attached `CALayer` and an image set on it. When I click the button, the image flips!

```
_zoomButton = [NSButton new];
[_zoomButton setBordered:NO];
[_zoomButton setButtonType:NSMomentaryChangeButton];
[_zoomButton setTitle:@""];
[_zoomButton setWantsLayer:YES];
[_zoomButton setImage:s_zoomImage];
[_zoomButton sizeToFit];
```

`s_zoomImage` is just an NSImage loaded from resources:

```
namespace
{
    NSImage *s_zoomImage; // No static variables in Objective-C.
}

+ (void)initialize
{
    [super initialize];

    NSString *const zoomImagePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Zoom.png" ofType:nil];
    s_zoomImage = [[[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:zoomImagePath] autorelease];
}
```

At first the button displays correctly, but if I click it, the image (`s_zoomImage`) flips vertically! Any ideas?

Comment: Does it remain flipped or is it flipped only while the button is being clicked?   Also, can you add the code for retrieving the button?

Comment: @gaige it remains permanently flipped after clicking. The code for loading the image is uninteresting, but I've added it anyway.

Comment: I'm assuming this doesn't happen if you don't use `-setWantsLayer`, since its probably the coordinate swap which is at issue here. Can you not use a layer-backed view for that button?  Otherwise you might need to make the image part of the layer instead of having the button handle it or even override the `NSButtonCell` and draw the image yourself.

Comment: @gaige yes, if I remove `setWantsLayer`, it works fine (except the opacity doesn't work). Is a "layer-backed view" the parent view but with `setWantsLayer` set as well?

Comment: Layer-backed views are any view where you use `-setWantsLayer`, but you don't use `-setLayer:` to set the layer manually (which would make it a layer-hosting view).  Layer-hosting views don't handle subviews well (docs say at all, but there are tricks), causing drawing side-effects.   So, as long as your parent views are all layer-backed or you don't have '-setWantsLayer`, you should, theoretically, be fine. However, that's not what is happening.